# Is this dynamic query vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I am rather new to SQL in C# and I need some advice on SQL injection.

```
public System.Linq.IQueryable findBy(List<String> lWhere) 
{
        string sWhere;

        foreach (var (sQueryPart, i) in lWhere.Select((Value, i) => (Value, i)))
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                sWhere = sQueryPart;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                sWhere += " = " + sQueryPart;
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                sWhere += " and " + sQueryPart;
            } 
            else
            {
                sWhere += " = " + sQueryPart;
            }

        }
        
        return this.TABLE.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE {0}", sWhere);
}
```

This method gets a list with entries like {"COLUMN1", "VALUE1" , "COLUMN2", "VALUE2"...}

After that, I build my `Where` clause using this list and enter it into the select statement.

First of all, the list might get replaced by a dictionary, actually I am pretty sure of that.

Secondly my question, is this safe against SQL injection? There shouldn't be user input other then using the method in program code, but no manual entries after that.

**EDIT**: it is important that I do not know the number of where clauses used, it could range from 1 to 4

Comment: You can still use parameters there, simply adding the parameter string and the values instead of directly editing the query. This way even if anyone maintaining the list/dictionary accidentally allows a broken query, the DB is still safe.

Comment: Yes, the `{0}` is the right way to pass parameters to `FromSqlRaw`, but you can't pass entire `where` clauses that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your SQL query manually by concatenating strings, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Full stop.

I don't understand why you are even doing this, as your code implies you are using Entity Framework. Which adds methods on your database entities to allow you to dynamically chain as many `.Where()` clauses as you require, precisely to remove the need for you to write SQL yourself, for example:

```cs
var results = dbContext.Table
    .Where(t => t.Column1 == "foo")
    .Where(t => t.Column2 == 42);
```

which will generate and execute SQL along the lines of:

```sql
select *
  from Table
 where Column1 = 'foo'
   and Column2 = 42;
```

**If you are using Entity Framework properly, you should almost never have to write any SQL yourself.** EF will generate it for you, in a way that is not susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: afaik i need a seperate .Where() for each statement, so .Where().Where() ... which i dont know how to make dynamic for 1-4 .where()


other then going for the lenght of my dictionary and using that for a switchcase and having multiple possible returns...

Comment: @coolkid What is the use case that makes it required to be dynamic, though?

Comment: @Nyerguds i require the findBy method multiple times for multiple tables (which isnt a problem) in my project, sometimes i just dont need a second where clause, sometimes i need a forth

Comment: @coolkid you can repeat `query = query.Where(...);`, that will combine fine

Answer (score 0):

As long as the List of strings is not formed from user input you are safe from SQL Injection; however, this is still bad code:

1. You should not do select * From. That’s bad because if the table gets a new column that you don’t need -and it may very well be huge binary data- you will end up getting it without needing it, slowing your app considerably.
2. It’s better to create a stored procedure with parameters for filtering the data. That way, you protect your code from SQL Injection and you can still branch your SQL statement to perform the filtering based on the parameters passed.
3. If at any point in time your List of Strings is gathered from user input, your code will be vulnerable.

Comment: on 2: stored procedures and parameters are two entirely orthogonal concepts; there may or may not be advantages (and disadvantages) of stored procedures, but the only relevant aspect here is *parameters*, and you can get every advantage of that *without* using stored procedures

Comment: @marc gravel. I know that. You don’t need a stored procedure but they are an excellent alternative, plus de fact that you don’t need to rebuild your app to change the internal behavior, which to me, is huge. I simply proposed an alternative.